# Get monthly max EVI from Modis merged collections in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have the following code to do four steps:

1- Load MODIS MOD13Q1 and MYD13Q1 datasets

2- Merge collections

3- Import EVI data with good QA

4- Calculate monthly max EVI values for every pixel

The code works with no error. But when I download a test data for a month (e.g., Oct 2010) from AρρEEARS and calculate max EVI in R it gives me different results for most of pixels.

It seems there is something wrong in my code but I couldn't figure it out. I would appreciate any assistance

Code

```
 // roi 
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[13.473092187466195, -20.861424970758563],
          [13.473092187466195, -35.51661935495365],
          [36.76410781246619, -35.51661935495365],
          [36.76410781246619, -20.861424970758563]]], null, false);

// Load MODIS MOD13Q1 dataset
var MOD13Q1 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD13Q1')
  .filterDate('2002-07-01','2022-12-31')
  .filterBounds(roi)
print(MOD13Q1);

// Load MODIS MYD13Q1 dataset
var MYD13Q1 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MYD13Q1')
  .filterDate('2002-07-01','2022-12-31')
  .filterBounds(roi)
print(MYD13Q1);

// merge collections
var MOD_merged = MOD13Q1.merge(MYD13Q1)
print(MOD_merged)


// Import EVI data with good QA
var mask = function(im) {
  return im.updateMask(im.select("SummaryQA").eq(0));
};

var EVIs = ee.ImageCollection(MOD_merged)
.map(mask)
.select("EVI")
.filterBounds(roi);


// sort by date
var MOD_merge_sorted = EVIs.sort("system:time_start")
.filterBounds(roi);
print(MOD_merge_sorted)



// Calculate monthly max EVI values
var start_date = ee.Date("2002-07-01");
var end_date = ee.Date("2022-12-31");

var monthly_images = function(IC) {
    
  // Get number of months in interval
  var n_months = ee.List.sequence(0, end_date.difference(start_date, "month").round().subtract(1));
    
  // Iterate monthly max over all months in the interval
  var images = n_months.map(function(n) {
    
    // Get images for given month
    var start = start_date.advance(n, "month");
    var end = start.advance(1, "month");
    var filtered = IC.filterDate(start, end);

    var max = filtered.max();
    

    return max.set("month", start.get("month"), "year", start.get("year"));
    });
    
    return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(images);
};

var ndvi_monthly_max = monthly_images(MOD_merge_sorted)
.filterBounds(roi)


print(ndvi_monthly_max,"max")


Map.addLayer(ndvi_monthly_max,{min:-2000,max:10000,palette:['Orange','Green']}, "EVIs")



//List EVI to Export max EVI collection
var list=ndvi_monthly_max.toList(246);
    for (var i=0;i<246;i++){
         var image=ee.Image(list.get(i))
         var yr= image.get("year")
        var name=ee.String(yr)
                .cat(image.get("month"))
                .getInfo();
     print(name);
         
    // Export collection        
         Export.image.toDrive({ 
               image: image,
               description: name,
               fileNamePrefix: name,
               scale: 250,
               region:roi,
               maxPixels: 3984216672400,
               fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
               folder: 'Modis_250_Monthly_Max_EVI',
               formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
               });
    }
```