# reduction of monthly Landsat and MODIS values

Tags: javascript, mean, google-earth-engine, libgee

Could someone tell me what could be causing the following error?
It turns out that I want to extract monthly values from a Landsat collection and when I do it for Landsat I can do it without problem. It takes time but you can compute the monthly average values for a long period of time (in the example 1984-2000, con 180 elementos!)
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f6f400cd364662916090111616cb5261

However, when I try to do the same for MODIS I get a memory error. I have been trying different date ranges and the best it allows me to do is only for two years
https://code.earthengine.google.com/9db2c86e0d4b3ace6389271610df3fde

I thought that maybe there are too many scenes to process, but when I want to do the calculation per year it does it without a problem, so obviously this is not the problem.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/c5b02943209358922691ef09121b14fe

Anyone else has happened? Do you know how it could be solved so as not to do the same procedure every two years over and over again?

From already thank you very much!

I am trying to calculate monthly values but using the same function in Lansat and MODIS gives me problems

Answer (score 0):

Your links are not available. However I guess the issue might be solved with setting `maxPixels` equal to something big. The example piece of code:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: merged_band,
    description: 'LC',
    region: geom_eurasia,
    fileNamePrefix: 'LC_Type2',
    folder: 'Eurasia',
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    maxPixels: 1e13
})
```

Comment: Thanks Daria!, now I have solved the problem with the links. The problem I have is when calculating the monthly values, which in the case of MODIS does not work (or works if I do not enter too many years). However, I found this alternative way to calculate the monthly values that does work for MODIS, I found this code in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76169745/get-monthly-max-evi-from-modis-merged- collections-in-google-earth-engine